# printf question with a const char* variable

Tags: c++, printf, const-char

I am stuck in a printf problem. I would appreciate if I can get some help here:
In the below code, I can see the font family get displaced correctly in first printf(),
but if I set it to variable, i only get an empty string. How can I put it in a variable and have the right values? I just don't want to type 'font.family().family().string().utf8().data()' everywhere?

I did this in the same method:

```
void myMethod() {
      const char* fontFamily = font.family().family().string().utf8().data();
      // get displayed correctly
      printf ("drawText1 %s \n", font.family().family().string().utf8().data());
      // get an empty string
      printf ("drawText2 %s \n", fontFamily);
}
```

And the signature of 'data()' is

```
class CString {
public:
    CString() { }
    CString(const char*);
    CString(const char*, unsigned length);
    CString(CStringBuffer* buffer) : m_buffer(buffer) { }
    static CString newUninitialized(size_t length, char*& characterBuffer);

    const char* data() const;
 //...

}
```

The signature of utf8() is

```
class String {
 CString utf8() const;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is this font library? C++ has no such thing. Maybe try including the type returned by `data()`. On a side note, any reason not to use `std::string`/`std::cout`?

Comment: It would help to know the signature of the `.data()` method.

Comment: And family.string() returns a temporary object of type CString?

Comment: What happened to the Law of Demeter?

Comment: We most likely need more details about data(). Can you post the full implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something in the chain of `font.family().family().string().utf8().data()` is returning a temporary object. In your first `printf`, the temporary object doesn't go out of scope until the `printf` returns. In the second `printf`, the temporary has been destroyed after the pointer assignment was made, and the pointer is now invalid. You're seeing a classic example of "undefined behavior".

There are two ways to fix this. Either make a copy of the data before the temporary gets destroyed, or make a reference to the temporary.  The copy is probably easiest and clearest, as long as the class has a copy operator. Assuming that `utf8()` generates a temporary `CString`, this would be

```
CString fontFamily = font.family().family().string().utf8();
printf ("drawText2 %s \n", fontFamily.data());
```

Comment: This is wrong. Temporaries are guaranteed to hang around for as long as need be (more or less).

Comment: A reference to a temporary is guaranteed, but a pointer to some internal data member? I think not.

Comment: There are no pointers in the quoted code. "Internal" pointers will be taken care of by the c++ constructor/destructor mechanism.

Comment: @Neil, the data() function is returning a char *, that is the pointer I am referring to. `utf8()` is probably returning a temporary CString, although that is just a guess.

Comment: @Mark It doesn't matter. Assuming a CString has a reasonable copy constructor the temporary  will remain valid. This is a guarantee made by the C++ language standard.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: What are you talking about? It is perfectly possible that any of the intermediate calls returns a temporary. This temporary will be killed immediately after the initialization of `fontFamily` (this leaving `fontFamily` hanging in the air). There are no guarantees in the language that would extend the lifetime of the temporary. Where did you get that idea? The only similar-sounding thing in C++ is guaranteed for references specifically, but we have no references in this example.

Comment: @AndreyT A temporary must live to the end of the expression it is part of.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Apparently you misunderstood. Mark must be talking about the *second* `printf` - the one that "doesn't work". The expression in this case is used to initialize a `const char* fontFamily` pointer. Once the initialization is over, the temporary is destroyed. And `fontFamily` pointer is left hanging in the air. Yet the OP is trying to print the string it is supposedly pointing to. The result is UB for the *second* `printf`. The first `printf` is indeed OK, becuse the whole thing is one expression.

Comment: @AndreyT Mark may have been talking about any number of things - my comment was about what he actually said. He nowhere mentioned the second printf.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Well, the topic of this question is (as it is clearly expressed by the OP): why the *second* `printf` doesn't work as expected, while the first one does.

Comment: @AndreyT and @Neil, thanks for making me see how ambiguous my language was. I'll clean up the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are caching a pointer that resides in the temporary returned by `utf8()` (as Mark and Neil have argued about). You'll have to change `fontFamily` to either a `CString` or `const CString &` to keep the result from `utf8()` in scope.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `data()` (assuming it is called on a std::string) does not necessarily return a null-terminated string. You almost certainly  want `c_str()`, which is defined to do so.